# How to Host Ghost Blog on Home Web Server

Tags: docker, vagrant, ghost-blog, ubuntu-15.04

I am running the Ghost Blog inside a docker container inside a virtual machine running Ubuntu Snappy Core OS.  This virtual machine is running on my home server, a C720 Chromebook cracked to run Lubuntu on bare-metal.

I can see the blog at localhost:2368 but do not know how to make it accessible to outside world?  I am port forwarding from the router to the C720, and have verified that I can host the blog from the native OS.  Now I am trying to get it running from inside the virtual machine.

Comment: You should try asking on superuser or serverfault and look a the vagrant or docker tagged questions regarding forwarding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make your VM run in bridge mode and pick up an address from your home router. Then expose the port on your container with something like this:

```
docker run -ti -p 2368:2368 ghost
```

Then you will be able to access your Ghost web site using the `Bridged` IP address

```
http://<bridged-ip>:2368
```